# Implementation of BitmapFactory.Options for Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview

I have 60 images that I use for my app. Each image is only (approx) 25KB in size. I use single letter naming convention for upper case, and double letters for lower case.

> a.png
>
> aa.png

In my layout I have 10 ImageViews, and I am programatically setting the image bitmap according to a word which I pull from a database.

My problem is, I may not have implemented the down sampling correctly. I add all 10 ImageViews to an ImageView array, and then find them to set their bitmap value based on the character array of the word from the database. Here is my method to set the Image View:

```
for(int j = 0; j < myWord.length(); j++){

    char[] chars = myWord.toCharArray();
    if(Character.isUpperCase(chars[j])){

        int imgID = getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(chars[j]).toLowerCase(), "drawable", getPackageName());

        letters[j].setTag(String.valueOf(chars[j]).toUpperCase());

        letters[j].setImageBitmap(CalculateSize.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), imgID, 75, 75));

    }else if(Character.isLowerCase(chars[j])){

        int imgID = getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(chars[j]) + String.valueOf(chars[j]), "drawable", getPackageName());

        letters[j].setTag(chars[j] + chars[j]);

        letters[j].setImageBitmap(CalculateSize.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),imgID, 75, 75));


}
```

Here are my methods to resize. I got it working for a 3 letter word with an `inSampleSize = 4` setting. However, I have been unable to get it working again no matter what I set it to:

```
    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight){

        // Height and Width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 12;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose smallest ratio as inSampleSize value.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }



        return inSampleSize;


    }


    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resID, int reqWidth, int reqHeight){

        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resID, options);

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resID, options);


    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I think the answer is to just use even smaller images.

I added debug logging to my code, which gave me the height and width of each image before it was sampled, and then it gave me the smallest ratio that was chosen.

Each image worked out to 930 x 1110 dp, and I was trying to sample it at 1/12th of that size, which was still growing the heap to 42MB + before crash.

I think what I need to do is resize the images to maybe 1/4 of the size they are now and downsample *those* by half, or even 1/4.

I can update this question for the 8 of you that read it to let you know if that works.

**Edit**: Updated the original size of the images and this works flawlessly.